# Meaning of "M.H.P." on a grave marker?

Tags: abbreviations

In translating the Latin-text gravestone of an early 18th century Capuchin, I encounter "M.H.P." at the end of the epitaph, followed by "A.M.D.G." --for "Ad maiorem Dei gloriam". I suspect the M.H.P. may abbreviate a phrase honoring Mary, mother of Jesus. Any guesses?

Here is the full text. Forward slash marks line breaks:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It might help if you posted the complete text, for context.

Answer (score 4):

Ainsworth (1749), Latin Dictionary appendix, for M.H.P. gives

> Monumentum heres posuit

His heir placed the monument.
Or, especially if the name of a donor is supplied as it is here:

*Superstites Missionarii* (the aforementioned missionaries)

> Memoriam hanc (posuit) posuerunt

(he/she)/they placed this memorial.

This section of his dictionary

> **Explicatio literarum et notarum frequentius in antiquis Romanorum monimentis occurrentium**
>   By Robert Ainsworth, Romani...

is available free as a [Google Book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LYMBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PP5&lpg=PP5&dq=Explicatio%20Literarum%20Et%20Notarum%20frequentius%20in%20antiquis&source=bl&ots=gnOACuwcGD&sig=ACfU3U2tiTCclHrMP-PR9dyClBI6DlAsvA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiypu_95ebnAhWKXsAKHVNICSMQ6AEwEXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Explicatio%20Literarum%20Et%20Notarum%20frequentius%20in%20antiquis&f=false) see p.61

Ainsworth is less useful with abbreviations for Catholic Friars; does A.S.C.D.P.F. give the title of the Capuchin Order which sent him ? Ainsworth gives DPF '*dis penatibus fecit/ fecerunt*' "for the funerary gods they did this."

Comment: A.S.C.D.P.F. = "A Sacra Congregatione de Propaganda Fide(i)" or some slight grammatical variation. The Congregation for the Propagation of the Faith gave the Tibet Mission to the Capuchins of Ancona in 1703.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help. I believe we have worked out the meaning of M.H.P. in the posted inscription: "Superstites Missionarii / Memoriam Hanc Posuerunt". This could be translated as "The surviving missionaries erected this memorial"...  (Careful reading of all the dates shows the inscription was made two years after P. dell Penna's death. (My apologies if I am not posting precisely as I should, I'm a newcomer.)

Comment: An impressive life, Fr Horatius, *meritis cumulatus*. *Superstites,* as you say, is 'survivors' (my mistake); since Tacitus uses it in conjunction with *bellorum,* is *Billorum* a misprint?